# What is the point of intersection with x-axis for this function?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I have this function: $$f(x)=\log(e^{2x}-5e^x+7)$$ I am supposed to find $f(x)=0$. I know that $log(x)=0$ when $x=1$. So I've put it this way: $$e^{2x}-5e^x+6=0$$ I don't know how to solve this, so I've tried substituting $e^x=t$ and I got $$t^2-5t+6=0$$ out of which I get two solutions: $t_1=3$ and $t_2=2$. When reverting back to $e^x$, I get: $e^x=3$ and $e^x=2$. Trying to solve for $x$, I get: $x_1=\log(3)$ and $x_2=\log(2)$.  However, according to Wolfram Alpha this is not correct.

I don't know how to solve this, and I am not allowed calculator on the test.

Do you have any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You did nothing wrong.

Comment: You did it right. Here is my try on Wolfram. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e^%282*x%29-5*e^%28x%29%2B6    http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ln%28e^%282*x%29-5*e^%28x%29%2B7%29

Comment: Not sure how people give links to wolfram alpha. When I tried I got the same answer as you. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ln%28e^%282*x%29-5*e^%28x%29%2B7%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $f(x) = 0$.  Then,

$$0 = \log(e^{2x} - 5e^{x} + 7)$$

Set both sides by $e$ to get

$$\begin{aligned}
e^{0} &= e^{\log(e^{2x} - 5e^{x} + 7)}\\
1 &= e^{2x} - 5e^{x} + 7
\end{aligned}$$

So...

$$\begin{aligned}
0 &= e^{2x} - 5e^{x} + 7 - 1\\
0 &= (e^x)^2 - 5e^x + 6\\
0 &= (e^x - 2)(e^x - 3)\\
\end{aligned}$$

Thus,

$$\begin{aligned}
e^x - 2 &= 0 & e^x - 3 &= 0\\
e^x &= 2 & e^x &= 3\\
x &= \ln(2) & x &= \ln(3)
\end{aligned}$$

The points of intersection are $(\ln(2), 0)$ and $(\ln(3), 0)$

Comment: But when I type this function into wolframalpha, the way it plots it makes me think that my solutions are wrong. Since it has one intersection on the negative side and one on the positive - close to 1.